# android emulator image for SDK level 19 not working

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, android-4.4-kitkat

I have most of the SDK level from 10 to L(21), for some reson 19, 4.4W(20) and L emulators do not start!
up until 18 i checked and it works.
Logcat shows that it screams about ld ails to find surface flinger dependency. (some .so)
i get native crash and stack traces in logcat and even the logo doesn't show, i tried simple nexus 5 configuration with no changes besides "no skin". tried both x86 and arm images and on both windows 7 host and ubuntu 14.04 host, it seems that the images are defective.

Anyone found out if something can be done ?

Comment: ok, the problem is not 100% the image, but the DPI\screen size.
apparently if i mark "use host GPU" i'm able to run nexus 7(2012) with SDK level 19 image. but the bigger screens, i can't surface flinger fails, probably issue with the screen driver.

Comment: there's a bug in google for issues similar to mine it seems that when the emulator height is more than 780 pixels it fails to start, i saw bugs on Intel graphics cards but i have Nvdia GT 520, pretty sure it's related to the screen size i have (22" which allows certain size, at home i got 23" which allows more and there using Host GPU it works).